# how do i configure the production environment in scriptcase

Tags: php

im working with scriptcase php code generator and as i build up my project, i uploaded it into my account in siteground.com. Now, i try to open it from the browser using mydomain.com/project_folder and it needs the initial configuaration.. all well till now, the prboblem starts when i get to the 3rd step where i need to setup or edit my db connection.. here it shows me this:

"404 - Not Found
The page you are trying to access does not exist.
If this error persists, please contact the website webmaster.
If you are the webmaster of this site make sure that:
You have uploaded correctly your files to the public_html directory which is the web-root of your account;
You have not misspelled the URL. Bear in mind that letters are case sensitive and no blank spaces are recommended;
In case you have applied SEO - SEF URL rewrite rules, make sure you have renamed the htaccess.txt file to .htaccess. If there is already a non-empty .htaccess file, check it and make sure the necessary rules are uncommented."

.. and, when i click on the rename connection, it shows: 
"Rename Connection
There are no connections saved on the production environment."

none of these reasons is the one causing the problem..than what should i do??

thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about siteground but important to give all files in the _lib directory of your app 777 permissions while you are setting it up

Also SC heavily uses sessions -- make sure you clear all cookies in your browser when moving from one SC app to another